# Full disk encryption

Tags: system-installation

Does the newest version of elementary OS installer have the option to do full disk encryption during install? If not how would I go about it? I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/1zevl6/encrypting_entire_osdrive/) reddit thread, is it still relevant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an option to encrypt the disk when you select the device for partitioning in the installer setup. This will encrypt the entire disk and not just the home partition (assuming you use the default partition scheme which is just one ext4 partition and one swap partition).

Comment: Works only in default installation mode. In custom install, there isn't option for partition encrypt - I don't know why :(